# Estoy haciendo un formulario de empleo y necesito enviar un archivo PDF

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, pdf

Estoy haciendo un formulario, con un input para **PDF**, hace la validación de que todos los campos estén llenados para así ser enviado a un correo predeterminado, pero cuando llega el correo el archivo del **PDF** no llega como deberia.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
window.onload = function() {
    var $form2 = $('#trip');
    function validateEmail(email) {
        var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
    }
    $('#trip').submit( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var campo_email = $('input[name="email"]').val();
        var campo_name =$('input[name="name"]').val();
        var campo_coment =$('textarea[name="coment"]').val();
        var campo_cv = $('input[type="file"]')[0].files[0].size;

        if(campo_email && campo_name && campo_coment && campo_cv){
            if(validateEmail(campo_email) === true && campo_name && campo_coment && campo_cv){
                /* EMAIL */
                    var datos = { action:'siteWideMessage', nombre:campo_name, comentario:campo_coment, email:campo_email, fileCurriculum:campo_cv };
                    $.post('<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php"); ?>', 
                        datos, function(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    });
                /* END EMAIL */
                $("#modal-up").hide();
                alert("Message sent!");
                window.location.reload(false);
            }else{
                alert("The mail is invalid");
            }
        }else{
            alert("Please, complete all the fields");
        }
    })
}
```

**código de functions.php **

/* SEND EMAIL POPUP */

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_siteWideMessage', 'wpse_sendmail' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_siteWideMessage', 'wpse_sendmail' );

    function wpse_sendmail()
    {
        $nombre  = $_POST["nombre"];
        $email = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["email"] );
        $comentario  = $_POST["comentario"];
        $fileCurriculum = $_POST["fileCurriculum"];

        // get the blog administrator's email address
        $to = "jobs@wildroverhostels.com";

        $message = 'Hola mi nombre es  ' . $nombre  . ' y mi correo es ' . $email . ' estoy postulando para ' . $comentario . 'mi Curriculum ' . $fileCurriculum;
        $subject = 'PUESTO DE TRABAJO';
        $headers = "From: <$email>" . "\r\n";

        // If email has been process for sending, display a success message
        if ( wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers ) ) {
            echo '<div class="mensaje" style="display:none;">';
            echo '<p>Thanks! Your personalised itinerary will be emailed very soon!</p>';
            echo '</div>';
        } else {
            echo 'An unexpected error occurred';
        }
        die();
    }
```

Comment: Podrias mirar por favor el [tour] y tambien [ask]?? No tengo ni idea del porque de los votos negativos, pero te recomiendo no poner imagenes de tu codigo, y tambien ser un poco mas claro con la informacion de la pregunta. El archivo, se esta generando correctamente como PDF? de eso estas seguro? si lo guardas en algun lado, lo podes abrir bien?

Answer (score 1):

Deberías sustituir `$_POST` por `$_FILES`:

```
$fileCurriculum = $_FILES["fileCurriculum"];
```

---

Tanto `$_POST` como `$_FILES` son superglobales de PHP, pero contienen información diferente:

- `$_POST` contiene toda la información de los formularios (menos los ficheros)
- `$_FILES` contienen todos los ficheros enviados al servidor a través de un formulario.

Por eso para leer el fichero debes usar `$_FILES` en lugar de `$_POST`.

Comment: Aunque esta respuesta puede servir para resolver el problema expuesto en la pregunta, esta publicación ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad. Sería ideal que indicaras en qué consiste el cambio que propones y por qué funcionaría en este caso. Lee [answer] para más información.